# HTML 5 - Need most current version of file when online

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am using HTML5 for an mobile application. I am using MVC.

The issue that i am facing is that the user when he is online is not able to retrieve the most current version of the file.

I have the following code

```
    NETWORK:
    *
```

which I thought would get the most current version of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the location your `.appcache` file under `NETWORK:` in addition to the wildcard.

Comment: My file does not end with .appcache. The filename that I have for manifest file is Manifest_3232.cshtml. Any suggestions.

Comment: If it **is** an appcache manifest file, are you able to rename it to `manifest3232.appcache` or similar?